# Google Cloud Armor rule partial URL encoded

Tags: spring-boot-actuator, google-cloud-armor

I added a new rule for deny all the external requests to 'actuator' .(spring endpoints) as following:
[image]

The rule works as expected until I am using partial decode URL like:

```
<host>/%61ctuator
```

Do you know any way or a better to define a rule like that that block encoded URLs as well?

Comment: I think must create a rule for that example. The rule is a string comparison without decoding first.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Armor [recently released](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/release-notes#August_31_2022) additional [operator functionality](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rules-language-reference#operations) that will allow for URL decoding of attributes within a given CEL rule match.

For example:

```
request.path.lower().urlDecode().contains("/actuator")
```